# Rails - Devise - Only allow registration if the user object already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

This may be a strange question, but it has come up in a project that I've been working on recently.

I have a Devise model called Student with a unique :sid parameter. The Student table in the database is already filled with Student objects with only :sid values set. I need to enable students to register using their :sid, setting the other attributes of the Student object and doing any Devise setup that is necessary.

How in the world should I set the registration up? Right now, I'm using a custom Devise RegistrationController with the following code:

```
# inside controllers/students/registration_controller.rb
def create
    if Student.exists?(:sid => params[:student][:sid].to_i)
        @student = Student.find_by_sid(params[:student][:sid].to_i)
        @student.update_attributes(params[:student])
        if @student.save
            set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
            sign_in(Student, @student)
        else
            set_flash_message :notice, :sign_up_failed
            redirect_to student_registration_path
        end
    else
        set_flash_message :error, :sid_not_found
        redirect_to new_student_registration_path
    end
end
```

This code merely updates the existing Student object.

I don't know if it makes more sense to store a list of valid :sids somewhere else, or if I should do something else entirely to make this work.

EDIT:
As for my main question, I'm wondering whether this is the best way to go about only allowing registrations from a pool of existing user objects that are selected using an arbitrary value.

Comment: It sounds like you already have the solution by overriding the Devise controller? What exactly is not working with this? My question would be about security-- how do you a student is registering with the correct sid? It seems like you simply need to run the registration automatically by sending codes to known email addresses.

Comment: As for you concern about security, sadly I'm ignoring that at this point due to time constraints. Ideally, the school's administrators would add all the information for each student and the registration step wouldn't be necessary, but I don't know if it is reasonable to require the administrators to set even just the name and sid for each student (I'm assuming that high schools have an average enrolment of ~800 students).

Comment: As for my main question, I'm wondering whether this is the best way to go about only allowing registrations from a pool of existing user objects that are selected using an arbitrary value.

Comment: I echo the security concern.  Seems to make the most sense to skip "registration" and have the students all created through the administrative interface (a simple CSV upload would do it).  Then students who come to the site could request access, which would simply send an email with a login link to their registered address, allowing them to log in and change their password.

Comment: Ideally, I'd go with @numbers1311407's solution, but I'll probably end up using tokens, as per Khaled's answer below, to make the system a little less labor-intensive to set up for admins. Thank you all for your comments, thanks to them I'm now able to create a concrete plan for registration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question right: you want to enable only those who have a certain token to register on the site and fill in their info. If this what you want to do then you could accomplish this by generating a token value (say 6 characters: 18ui7p) and store these in a separate table then if you want some one to register you send them a url that contains a valid token say

```
http://example.com/users/sign_up?token=18ui7p
```

and in your registrations controller you override `new` method to allow only a user that has a valid token (that you have generated and stored before in the db) to register as a user, the same in the `create` action, also don't forget to remove/mark the token after it is used.

This way if someone (say school admin) wants to add someone new in the system, they can generate a token and send it to the student in an email, which means you will provide an action that generates a token and send it to an email, of course this is accessible only by the admin.

I just found a gem called [devise_invitable](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable) which could do what you want, but you could just implement the solution yourself.

Comment: Thanks, this is probably the best solution given my constraints. 


Strangely, I had looked at devise_inevitable/tokens before and had decided that they wouldn't work for me for some reason (brain fart probably), but your solution has changed my mind.